# Need to understand the security flaw?

Tags: database-design, security

I am creating a database of encrypted value.

---

Let us say I store "John" which would be encrypted and stored as "Yoky".

```
John | Yoky
```

---

Now I store "Johnny" which would be encrypted and store as "Koaddy"

```
John   | Yoky

Johnny | Koaddy
```

---

Now with the above storage I will not get any kind of regex search functionality. If I wanted to search "Jo%" it will not work.

But what if I store the values after breaking them. as

```
Jo      |   Yoky , Koaddy
Joh     |   Yoky , Koaddy
John    |   Yoky , Koaddy
Johnn   |   Koaddy
Johnny  |   Koaddy
```

Here the regex searches will work "Jo%","Joh%" both will give Yoky and Koaddy, which is what I want.

I can see the obvious security flaw above that anyone can map out Jo,Joh.

So I have decided to store the encryption of these.

---

I will AES encrypt my stubs and store them.

```
qkjklewr!j==      |   Yoky , Koaddy
klkadsopos==      |   Yoky , Koaddy
oensd%21op==      |   Yoky , Koaddy
kaknvp23b02==     |   Koaddy
kashdi2094j==     |   Koaddy
```

---

While performing any type of search say, "Joh", I will first encrypt "Joh" then perform the search, therefore it will map to the AES encrypted value of "Joh",i.e,klkadsopos==

---

Note : Both the column will use different keys and algorithms to protect the data.

---

Note : This storage will be TDE encrypted. HDFS will be encrypted and I will be using Apache Solr for the rest.

I need to understand if I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming SQL Server here as you mention TDE. You can check out the improvements in Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver15

or this post about search columns: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-mimic-a-wildcard-search-on-always-encrypted-columns-with-entity-framework/

Comment: I have updated how I will be storing the data. Thank you for the articles, I am going through the second one, looks interesting.